# C++ : Error could not convert from std::vector<int>* to std::vector<std::vector<int> >

Tags: c++

I want to use `vector<int> adj[]` as my parameter and `vector<vector<int>>` as my return function type but doing that will cause an error : This happens when returning the vector adj.

```
could not convert adj from std::vector<int>* to std::vector<std::vector<int> >
          return adj;
```

How can I solve this issue ?

This is my program :

```
  vector<vector<int>>printGraph(int V, vector<int> adj[])
        {
             for ( int i = 0 ; i < V ; i ++)
             {
                for (auto x : adj[i])
                cout << x;
                cout<<"\n";
             }
             
             return adj;
        }
```

Comment: `adj` is not `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. Did you want to return anything at all from this function? I don't understand the purpose of the return since the function is named printGraph() and does output using cout.

Comment: `vector<int> adj[]` in a parameter list is another (IMHO bad) way to write `vector<int>* adj`, so you have a pointer there.

Comment: Don't make a function do multiple things (single responsibility principle). If the function is called print, it should only print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I got your are trying to convert the array of vectors to a vector of vectors.
Try to return an interval of elements of the original array.

```
return { adj, adj + V };
```

Answer (score 2):

I realized you are unnecessarily returning adj, if you just want to print you can do yourself a favor and use a void function instead check this code out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printGraph(int V, vector<int> adj[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        for (auto x : adj[i]) {
            cout << x << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> cat{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    vector<int> arr[4] = { cat, cat, cat, cat };
    printGraph(4, arr);
}
```